# how to reshape array to predict with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I made an LSTM model based on [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) where the model input batch shape is:

```
print(config["layers"][0]["config"]["batch_input_shape"])
```

returns:

```
(None, 1, 96)
```

Can someone give me a tip on how change my testing data to this array shape to match the model input batch size?

```
testday = read_csv('./data.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates=True)
testday_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(testday.values)

print(testday_scaled.shape)
```

returns

```
(96, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You need to use [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) and then add `None` to the first dimension.

```
import numpy as np
testday_scaled = np.swapaxes(testday_scaled, 0, 1)
testday_scaled = testday_scaled[None, ...]
```